# Formalizing the axioms of a specific group object in a slice category

Tags: category-theory

I have the following:

> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an arbitrary category and $B$ an object in $\mathcal{C}$. Consider the slice category $\mathcal{C}/B$ and an object $p : G \rightarrow B$. Use the notion of fiber product (over $B$) to write the axioms for $p : G \rightarrow B$ as a group object of the category $\mathcal{C}/B$

I don't understand what they meant by "fiber product (over $B$)". Also, does a group object in a category mean an object that can be endowed with a group structure? If yes, how does that work in this slice category?

Comment: A group object in $\mathcal{C}/B$ would have maps $m:G \times_{B} G \to G$ (multiplication), $i:G \to G$ (inverse), and $e:B \to G$ (identity).

Comment: How do we define the fiber product $G \times_B G$?

Comment: See for instance the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(category_theory)

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to work out the definition in the slice category $Set/B$, which will give you an intuition of why, if $B$ is a singleton, this is just a group in $Set=Set/1$. I will start for you, and let you finish :)

First of all, you need an object of $Set/B$, which is a function $u : E\to B$.

This function is equipped with a binary operation $m : u\times u\to u$, where $u\times u : E\times_B E\to E$ has already been defined to you. The notation is explained by the fact that fiber products, or pullbacks, in $Set$, are just binary product in the slice $Set/B$ (note in particular to what it corresponds the fiber product of two terminal maps $E \to 1\leftarrow F$!).

The function $u : E\to B$ is also equipped with a morphism $e : \perp\to u$ in $Set/B$ from the terminal object of $Set/B$ to $u$. Such terminal object is the identity function of $B$, $id_B : B\to B$, and then the morphism $e$ corresponds to a *section* of $u$, because the fact that $e$ is a morphism of that type means that $u\circ e=id$. Hence, $u$ is a surjective function, and $e$ is its right inverse.

Can you write down where the element $(x,y)\in E\times_BE$ goes under $m$? Can you write down the associativity and unit axioms?

So far, we have defined a monoid in $Set/B$. It remains to

- define the inversion operation $(-)^{-1} : E\to E$;
- write down the axiom that every element, multiplied with its inverse, "gives the identity". This is probably a bit tricky to write down, but try!